# ng-repeat y valores repetidos

Tags: angularjs

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
var options = ["option1", "option2", "option3"]

<div ng-repeat="fir in getTimes(3)">
<select ng-model="spAnswer[$index].importance">
    <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option}}">
        {{option}}
    </option>
</select>
</div>
```

Si tengo 3 selects: si en el segundo select he seleccionado el `option1`, en el primero y el tercero deberían aparecerme `option2` y `option3` para poder elegir.

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre algo para lograr lo que deseas de manera sencilla. Si creas una función con un filtro personalizado, podrías filtrar las opciones que no han sido seleccionadas. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo para que entiendas mejor lo que he intentado explicar:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {

  $scope.selects = ["", "", ""];

  $scope.options = ["option1", "option2", "option3"];

  $scope.filterOpts = function (selindex) {
    return function (item) {
      var ind = $scope.selects.indexOf(item);
      return ind == selindex || ind < 0;
    }
  };

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <select ng-repeat="(ind, val) in [1, 2, 3]" ng-model="selects[ind]">
        <option value="">Selecciona una</option>
        <option ng-repeat="item in options | filter:filterOpts(ind)" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de utilizar

```
<option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option}}">
```

crea una función que te devuelva los options filtrados. En el controlador:

```
function getOptions(index){
// Si index es mayor que 0, es el segundo o tercer select y mira qué valor tiene el anterior.
  if(index > 0){
    var excluido = spAnswer[index-1].importance;
    // Devuelve todas las opciones menos la excluida.
    return options.filter(function(o){
      return o !== excluido;
    });
  }else{
    // Es el primer select, devuelve todas las opciones.
    return options;
  }
}
```

Entonces, llama a la función que genera las opciones en el ngrepeat:

```
<option ng-repeat="option in getOptions($index)" value="{{option}}">
```

Comment: he editado la pregunta, si puede ayudarme

Comment: Y yo he editado la respuesta en reflejando los cambios :)

Comment: como puedo llamar al getoptions? , no llama al metodo he tenido que cambiarlo a $scope.getOptions=function(index){ pero claro el return no vale en este caso

Comment: solucionado, gracias

Comment: Sí, si usas $scope tienes que reescribirlo de esa manera, y el return sí que vale en ese caso. Si no dependen por orden los select, en lugar de mirar el valor anterior tendrás que hacer una lista aparte con las opciones que ya se han escogido.

Answer (score 0):

Esta puede ser una solución, html:

```
<div ng-controller="MiControl">
  <div ng-repeat="fir in getTimes(3)">
    <select 
     ng-model="spAnswer[$index].importance"
     ng-options="op for op in optionsAux[$index]"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

tu controlador:

```
app.controller('MiControl',['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.spAnswer = [{},{},{}];
  $scope.options = ["option1", "option2", "option3"];
  $scope.optionsAux =  generateList($scope.options);

  $scope.getTimes = function(n){
    var a = [];
    for(var p = 0; p < n; p++){
        a.push(p);
    }
    return a;
  }
  //Esta función crea un arreglo de arreglos disminuyendo uno
  // por cada iteración.
  function generateList(array){
    var mainArray = [];

    for(var p = 0; p < array.length; p++){
       var auxA = [];
       for(var x = p; x < array.length; x++){
         auxA.push(array[x]);
       }
       mainArray.push(auxA);
    } 
    return mainArray;
  }
}]);
```

Comment: esta opcion no me sirve debido a que si tengo 3 picklist:
en el primero me parecen las opciones :option1,option2,option3
en el segundo me aparece  :option2,option3

y lo que necesito por ejemplo, si en el segundo picklist he seleccionado el option1; en el primero y tercero deberian aparecerme option2,option3 para poder elegir

Comment: solucionado, me diste una idea

Comment: jaja me alegro, podrías marcar tu pregunta como solucionado por favor.